# Read XML with C# with custom deserializer

Tags: c#, .net, xml, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize a piece of XML offered by some API. However this API is dumb, for example, a bool is not true, but True. And having an element

```
[XmlElement("Foo")]
public bool Foo { get;set; }
```

and then the matching XML:

```
<...><Foo>True</Foo></...>
```

does NOT work, because True is not a valid representation of bool (the API is written in Python, which is, I think, more forgiving).

Is there any way to put some attribute on my property `Foo` to say to the system: when you encounter this element, put it through this converter class?

Edit:
The XML is large, and most of them are stupid, not directly convertible objects, like `234KB`, which I need to parse to the exact value.

Do I need to write a wrapper property for each of them?

Comment: Is the structure complicated enough that you really need to use the built-in XML serialization? Could you just do it by hand? LINQ to XML usually makes this pretty simple.

Comment: In python true is case sensitive and has to be capitalized.

Comment: @Jon good point, but I wonder if it is possible the way I want it without using a custom type (instead of bool). I don't have a problem with writing a custom converter class.

Comment: I would think C# could parse 'True' to a bool.. are you sure this is the reason it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a backing property:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool Foo 
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Equals(FooXml, "true", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        }
        set
        {
            FooXml = value.ToString();
        }
    }

    [XmlElement("Foo")]
    public string FooXml { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's possible, but I'm trying to do as little plumbing as possible.